# Service Worker Error DOMException: Only secure origins are allowed

Tags: javascript, push-notification, service-worker

when I try to implement it in my website it's show error like this. Please help.

**Service Worker Error DOMException: Only secure origins are allowed.**

```js
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && 'PushManager' in window) {
  console.log('Service Worker and Push is supported');

  navigator.serviceWorker.register("{{ 'sw.js' | asset_url }}")
  .then(function(swReg) {
 registration.pushManager.subscribe({ userVisibleOnly: true })
 .then(function(subscription) {
            console.log('endpoint:', subscription.endpoint);
        });
    console.log('Service Worker is registered', swReg);

    swRegistration = swReg;
    initialiseUI();
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.error('Service Worker Error', error);
  });
} else {
  console.warn('Push messaging is not supported');
  pushButton.textContent = 'Push Not Supported';
}
```

[image: "Only secure origins are allowed" error message in devtools console]

Answer (score 1):

You should implement web push notification on secured web site.  Install SSL Certificate and try from https://urhome.byethost16.com/push

But you don't need SSL Certificate on localhost.  Try to check from [localhost](http://localhost).

Answer (score 0):

Transport layer security (TLS) uses localhost or 127.0.0.1 as secure origins try using it I think your problem will be solved